# How to vertically align table values to middle

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a seaborn box plot with a summary stats table below the plot with the following code:

```py
#Packages
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Directories
export_directory = "C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/"

#Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'entity': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                   'score': [33, 34, 35, 35, 36, 49, 44, 46, 45, 48, 62, 60, 62, 63, 61],
                   'category': ['sm', 'sm', 'sm', 'sm', 'sm', 'md', 'md', 'md', 'md', 'md', 'lg', 'lg', 'lg', 'lg', 'lg']})

#Create seaborn boxplot
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(y=df['score'], x=df['category'])

#Create pivot table for count & median values, then transpose the table so it aligns with x axis later
pivotdf = df.pivot_table(index='category', values='score', aggfunc={'count','median'}).T
#Flip column order to align with x axis in plot
pivotdf = pivotdf[pivotdf.columns[::-1]]

#Create a matplotlib table from the pivotdf
pivottable = table(ax1, pivotdf, cellLoc='center', loc='bottom')

#Add the matplotlib table beneath the boxplot
ax1.add_table(pivottable)

#Remove x axis label & ticks since they overlap with the pivot table
ax1.set(xlabel=None)
ax1.set_xticks([])

#Save the figure
fig1.savefig(export_directory+'boxplotfig.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Boxplot output from current code]

After running this, I noticed the table values were centered, but the vertical alignment was set to “top” and looked squished against the top of the cells. How can I vertical align to the middle?

I’ve tried:

```
ax1.table1.set_text_props(va=‘center’)
```

Comment: `df.style.set_properties(**{"vertical-align": "text-center"})`? or something along those lines. I haven't tested this.

Comment: Maybe `for (row, col), cell in table1.get_celld().items(): cell.set_text_props(va=‘center’)`?

Comment: I’ve tried your approach @TrentonMcKinney and it works for dataframes but unfortunately not the matplotlib table that I am dealing with. Even center aligning the df before converting to a matplotlib table doesn’t do the trick.

Comment: @JohanC I tried this approach and it doesn’t vertically align the output matplotlib table but it also doesn’t result in any errors. Seems like we could be close.

Comment: You might want to update pandas and matplotlib. The numbers in my table do not overlap the horizontal lines the way yours do. [plot / table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z70aZ.png)